# Syntax for SQL - IBM Solutions Server

Tags: sql, db2

My current Query includes:

```
SELECT  case when PROGRAMID = 'OTP' then 'SEA' else 'GHC' end AS Clinic
```

I just want to add a PROGRAMID 'SKC' to the list and all my attempts have failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT (case when PROGRAMID in ('OTP', 'SKC') then 'SEA' else 'GHC'
        end) as Clinic
```

Comment: I'll try it tonight.

Comment: It works! I didn't exactly get the results I wanted, but it gave the syntax I needed. Than you so much.